# Alternative in parenthesis before or after?

Tags: sentence-patterns, variants, parentheses

When a sentence describes there are multiple alternatives, but one specific is the common one, it can specify the common in parenthesis.  But there are multiple ways to do it.

For example, should it be

> The ion temperature may be different from (usually lower than) the electron temperature.

or

> The ion temperature may be different (usually lower than) from the electron temperature.

or

> The ion temperature may be different (usually lower than) the electron temperature.

or

> The ion temperature may be different (usually lower) than the electron temperature.

or, avoiding the parenthesis,

> The ion temperature may be different than the electron temperature. Usually lower.

Comment: To weed out some of them, the sentence should make sense if the parenthesised phrase is removed.

Comment: I  like "The ion temperature may be different (usually lower) than the electron temperature." because it is concise.

Comment: Another option is to reword the sentence to avoid the parenthetical nesting. For example: "The ion temperature may differ from the electron temperature, usually by being lower." This is often a better option than trying to interpolate a parenthetical phrase that doesn't flow smoothly in parallel with the primary statement within which it appears.

Answer (score 1):

Two rules apply here

1. The sentence should read correctly without the parentheses
2. The sentence should also read correctly if the operative part of the parentheses (i.e. excluding 'usually') replaced the comparison before it in the main sentence.

Rule 1 excludes sentence number 3, and sentences 4 and 5 are only allowed in US English where "different than" is a valid comparison.
Rule 2 excludes sentence number 2 ("The ion temperature may be lower than from the electron temperature.") and makes sentence 4 only valid in US English.

So

- In UK English only sentence 1 is permitted (though sentence 5 could be made correct by substituting 'from' for 'than')
- In US English sentences 4 and 5 are correct, and possibly 1 if you permit 'different from'.

Comment: Oh, that is way more complex than I expected!